# How to replace the last character in JavaScript with a word?

Tags: javascript

I checked out all the answers related to this matter and none of these apply. I'd like to build a simple script asking about the name and the gender. If a person identifies herself as a woman, the script will delete the last character from the string and replace it with the word 'woman', e.g. Agnes => Agnewoman, Maya => Maywoman etc. I know that strings are immutable in JavaScript. I used a colloquial language to express my idea.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Let's get started</title>
<link href="../_css/site.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script>
var name = prompt("What's your name", " ");
var answer = prompt("Are you a woman?", " ");
</script>

</head>

<body>
<div class="wrapper">
  <header>
    JAVASCRIPT <span class="amp">and</span> jQUERY
  </header>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="main">
      <h1>Variables</h1>

      <script>
        if (answer == "yes" || answer == "Yes" || answer == "YES" || answer == "y" || answer == "Y"){
          document.write(...);
        } else {

        };
      </script>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please check my comment under @alpadev's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see my proposed solution [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7on4jen6/)

```
if (answer == "yes" || answer == "Yes" || answer == "YES" || answer == "y" || answer == "Y"){
   name = name.slice(0, -1);
   document.write(name+"woman");
} else {
   document.write(name);
}
```

Comment: I tried this one and replaced the first part with an array.

Answer (score 4):

Weird problem, but the solution is Easy:
remove the last character and append "woman"

name = name.substring(0, name.length - 1) + "woman";

Edit: If a user entered an empty string, this would still work, as substring treats negative parameters as 0.

Comment: I changed your code like this:       <script>
        if (name.length > 0){
            name = name.substring(0, name.length - 1) + "woman";
            document.write(name);
        } else {
            document.write("<p>Hello, handsome!</p>")
        };
      </script>

and works perfectly.

Comment: I don't understand this part "name.length > 0". Could you explain me?

Answer (score 1):

I would change your gender question to a confirm - then you don't have to worry about the different options that could be entered. Then in the javascript it is as simple as checking whether the answer is true or not (you can use if(answer == true) or the shorthand way as below.

```
var name = prompt("What's your name", " ");
var namePortion = name.substring(0, name.length-1);

var answer = confirm("Are you a woman?");
if (answer){
  console.log(namePortion + 'woman')
} else {
  console.log(namePortion +'man')
};
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand this code correctly. Where do you put "var answer = confirm[...]" ?(I mean which section of the code...<head>, <body>)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
var gender = 'man';
if (answer == "yes" || answer == "Yes" || answer == "YES" || answer == "y" || answer == "Y") {
    gender = 'woman'
}

console.log(name.substring(0, name.length-1) + gender);
```

Comment: It would be more elegant to put all possible answers in an array: `var answers = ['Yes', 'YES',  ...];` and check this in the if clause: `if (answers.includes(answer)) { // do something }`.

Comment: @alpadex It works! I made some changes in your code. I didn't use "var gender = "man", just "woman" instead. Besides, I replaced console.log with document.write.

Comment: It'd be even more elegent to use a regex like `/y(es|eah)?/i`, and do `'/y(es|eah)?/i'.test(answer);`.

Comment: @5aledmaged I guess, I need more time to test your answer and add more possibilities.

Comment: @cezar I tried your solution and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function showValue(){
var inp = document.getElementById("input_id").value;
var slp = document.getElementById("select_id").value;
if(slp== 'woman'){
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = inp.slice(0,-1)+'woman';
}
else document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = inp;
}
```

```html
Name: <input id='input_id'>
gender : <select id='select_id'>
  <option value="man">man</option>
  <option value="woman">woman</option>
</select>
<button onclick='showValue()'>show</button>
<p id='result'></p>
```

Try slice(0,-1)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use **replace** method

```
name.replace(name.charAt(name.length-1), "women");
```